# How to store the Cookie permanently in my Android application

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpurlconnection, jsessionid

I have used the following code:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

It is working fine. But, when the user restarts the application, the cookie gets deleted, and I can't use it for further rest calls.

How can I store the cookie permanently in the Android app?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways using which you can save data permanently (until you can'y clear app data).

1. SharedPreference
2. Local Database (SQLite / Room - Recommending)

Using above listed methods you can store you data and also get those data after restart of application/mobile phone.

You can get an idea of access of above listed methods using below links.

1. SharedPreference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm
2. SQLite : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-and-add-data-to-sqlite-database-in-android/
3. Room : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-perform-crud-operations-in-room-database-in-android/

Thank you.